computed property is not updated by reactive dependency updating
I'm trying to create a class with a ComputedRef<> field, and assign its object to a component property. But the computed property is not updated.
/// Student.ts

import { computed, type ComputedRef } from "vue";

export class Student {
    age: number;
    adult: ComputedRef<boolean>;

    constructor(age: number) {
        this.age = age;

        const that = this;
        this.adult = computed(() => that.age >= 18);
    }
}

/// StudentComponent.vue

<script setup lang="ts">
import { Student } from './student';
import { ref } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps<{
    data: Student
}>();
const dataRef = ref(props.data);

</script>

<template>
    <div>age: {{ dataRef.age }}</div>
    <div>adult: {{ dataRef.adult }}</div>
    <button @click="++dataRef.age;">+1</button>
    <button @click="--dataRef.age;">-1</button>
</template>
</script>

/// App.vue

<script setup lang="ts">
import StudentComponent from './StudentComponent.vue';
import { Student } from './student';

const student = new Student(18);

</script>

<template>
    <StudentComponent :data="student"></StudentComponent>
</template>

The result is below:

"adult" value is not changed when "-1" button is clicked. How should I do it?

Here the problem is that Student instance and so "age" property is not reactive. That it's wrapped with dataRef won't change the way it works. You will naturally have several kinds of problems by using reactivity with classes. I'd suggest to just avoid them without a good reason.

@EstusFlask Understood and solved it. Thank you so much.

The computed value will only update when any referenced 'ref's are updated. Since the class property 'age' is just a number not a ref, the computed property will not know when a new value is set.
It should work if you update your class to use a ref for the 'age' property:
import { ref, type Ref, computed, type ComputedRef } from "vue";

export class Student {
    age: Ref<number>;
    adult: ComputedRef<boolean>;

    constructor(age: number) {
        this.age = ref(age);
        this.adult = computed(() => this.age.value >= 18);
    }
}

make sure you update the age property through using studentInstance.age.value = newValue.
You can also 'hide' the fact that you're using a ref in the class using getter/setter with a private property
import {ref, type Ref, computed, type ComputedRef } from 'vue'


export class Student {
  _age: Ref<number>
  adult: ComputedRef<boolean>

  get age() {
    return this._age.value
  }

  set age(newVal: number) {
        this._age.value = newVal
}

  constructor(age: number) {
    this._age = ref(age)
    this.adult = computed(() => this._age.value >= 18)
  }
}

which will let you update values normally studentInstance.age = newValue

The problem with a class like this is that it behaves incorrectly when refs are accidentally unwrapped, e.g. when Student is used in data(), but there can be random situations that lead to this. This at least makes Student type and specifically ComputedRef type incorrect because student.adult becomes a value rather than a ref

I would have though accidentally unwrapping refs are a risk anytime you use the reactive system. How would using a class like this be different than the examples for basic state management Vue Docs: basic state management, or using a composable. Using a composable is probably more 'vue' approved than a class like this, but it seems like a composable would have similar pit falls.

Yes, that's right. Generally this the problem with an instance that has ref properties, it's  inherent to class instances and doesn't exist with regular FP use of reactivity api, even with TS

// Student.ts
import { computed, ref, type ComputedRef } from "vue";

export class Student {
    age = ref(0);  // Make age reactive using ref
    adult: ComputedRef<boolean>;

    constructor(initialAge: number) {
        this.age.value = initialAge;
        
        this.adult = computed(() => this.age.value >= 18);
    }
}

// StudentComponent.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import { Student } from './student';

const props = defineProps<{
    data: Student
}>();

</script>

<template>
    <div>age: {{ data.age.value }}</div>
    <div>adult: {{ data.adult }}</div>
    <button @click="data.age.value++">+1</button>
    <button @click="data.age.value--">-1</button>
</template>

// App.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import StudentComponent from './StudentComponent.vue';
import { Student } from './student';

const student = new Student(18);
</script>

<template>
    <StudentComponent :data="student"></StudentComponent>
</template>

The issue was that reactivity of vue system needs to track changes to properties, and simple class properties aren't reactive by default. By using ref(), we make the age property reactive, allowing vue to track changes and update computed properties and the UI accordingly.
